# Extremly poor polynomial fitting with SVR in sklearn

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, scikit-learn, ridge-regression

I try to fit an *obvious* around degree 5 polynomial function.
Much to my despair, `sklearn` bluntly refuses to match the polynomial, and instead output a 0-degree like function.

Here is the code.  All you need to know is that `sp_tr` is a `m`×`n` matrix of `n` features and that I take the first column (`i_x`) as my input data and the second one (`i_y`) as my output data.

```
    x_min = sp_tr[:,i_x].min()
    x_max = sp_tr[:,i_x].max()
    xs = numpy.arange( x_min, x_max, (x_max - x_min)/100 )

    sp_clf = SVR( degree=5 )
    sp_clf.fit( sp_tr[:,[i_x]], sp_tr[:,i_y] )
    ys = sp_clf.predict( numpy.transpose([xs]) )
```

Then I plot xs, ys as a red line, and I plot the data learned from a blue dots (`sp_tr[:,i_x]` to `sp_tr[:,i_y]`).  Here are the result I obtain, first with the kernel ridge method, second with SVR.

[image: Polynomial fitting with kernel ridge]
[image: Polynomial fitting with SVR]

What happened ?  How could SVR and Kernel Ridge go so wrong to believe the relation is constant ?  What could be done to have something more satisfying ?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: For a small dataset out-of-fold variant of cross-validation could be appropriate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, you need to tune your parameters.  Here's the [sklearn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html):

> The free parameters in the model are C and epsilon.

and their descriptions:

> C : float, optional (default=1.0)
>
> Penalty parameter C of the error term.
>
> epsilon : float, optional (default=0.1)
>
> Epsilon in the epsilon-SVR model. It specifies the epsilon-tube within which no penalty is associated in the training loss function with points predicted within a distance epsilon from the actual value.

It looks like you have an under-penalized model, it is not punished harshly enough for straying away from the data.  Let's check.

I generated some polynomial data that is on approximately the same scale as yours:

```
xs = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
ys = 400*(xs - 2*xs*xs + xs*xs*xs) - 20
scatter(xs, ys, alpha=.25)
```

[image: CubicSVR]

And then fit the SVR with the default parameters:

```
clf = SVR(degree=3)
clf.fit(np.transpose([xs]), ys)
yf = clf.predict(numpy.transpose([xs]))
```

Which gives me essentially the same issue as you:

[image: UnderPenalizedSVR]

Using the intuition that the parameters are under-penalizing the fit, I adjusted them:

```
clf = SVR(degree=3, C=100, epsilon=.01)
```

Which gives me a pretty good fit:

[image: GoodFitSVM]

In general, whenever your model has free parameters like this, it is very important to tune them carefully.  `sklearn` makes this as convenient as possible, it supplies the [grid_search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) module, which will try many models in parallel with different tuning parameters and choose the one that best fits your data.  Also important is getting the measurement of *best fits your data* correct, as the model fit measured using the training data is not a good representation of the model fit on unseen data.  Use cross validation or a sample of held out data to examine how well your model fits.  In your case, I would recommend using cross validation with `GridSearchCV`.

Comment: Thank you.  I also realized I needed to specify `'polynomial'` as the kernel function for `KernelRidge`.  There are less than 50 data points in my data set, I'm not sure a cross-validation would be more relevant than a look-a-it, because for it to be relevant, I would remove so many useful information for my training set that it could compromise the validity of the model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which gets to most of the issue. 

However, if you specifying kernel='poly' in the SVR call (the default kernel is 'rbf', where specifying the degree has no effect I believe), the straight line prediction returns.

Answer (score 0):

For the polynomial kernel, specify kernel='poly' and also try also rescaling your data, as well as tuning your parameters C and epsilon as Matthew described.

```
>>> from sklearn import preprocessing
>>> X = [[ 1., -1.,  2.],
...      [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
...      [ 0.,  1., -1.]]
>>> X_scaled = preprocessing.scale(X)

>>> X_scaled                                          
array([[ 0.  ..., -1.22...,  1.33...],
       [ 1.22...,  0.  ..., -0.26...],
       [-1.22...,  1.22..., -1.06...]])
```

"The data will then have zero mean and unit variance".

Copied verbatim from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324071/scaling-data-in-scikit-learn-svm